# How to select data from joined table as a table type?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to build de-normalised view that handles reference data in table type.

```
create table reftab (id number, name varchar2(40), details varchar2(1000));
/
create table basictab (id number, name varchar2(300), contract varchar2 (20));
/
create or replace type reftype is object (id number, name varchar2(40), details varchar2(1000));
/
create or replace type reftypetab as table of reftype;
/
insert into basictab values (1, 'aaa', 'c1');
insert into basictab values (2, 'aab', 'c1');
insert into basictab values (3, 'aaa', 'c2');
insert into basictab values (4, 'aaa', 'c3');

insert into reftab values (1, 'asd', 'aaa');
insert into reftab values (1, 'asg', 'ass');
insert into reftab values (1, 'ash', 'add');
insert into reftab values (1, 'asf', 'agg');
insert into reftab values (3, 'asd', 'aaa');
insert into reftab values (3, 'ad', 'aa');
insert into reftab values (4, 'asd', 'aaa');
insert into reftab values (4, 'as', 'a');
insert into  values (4, 'ad', 'aa');
/
```

With such data I'd like to have view that contains 4 rows of `basictab` with additional column that is `reftypetab` and contains all ref data joined on `id`.

I know I can obtain it by:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pipef (p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN reftypetab PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (select * from reftab where id = p_id) LOOP
    PIPE ROW(reftype(x.id, x.name, x.details));   
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
/

SELECT id, pipef(id)
FROM  reftab
group BY id;
/
```

but is there any better way without function to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current set-up gets:

```
SELECT id, pipef(id) as result
FROM  reftab
group BY id;

        ID RESULT(ID, NAME, DETAILS)                                                                                               
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(1, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(1, 'asg', 'ass'), REFTYPE(1, 'ash', 'add'), REFTYPE(1, 'asf', 'agg'))      
         4 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(4, 'as', 'a'), REFTYPE(4, 'ad', 'aa'))                                     
         3 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(3, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(3, 'ad', 'aa'))
```

You could use [the `collect()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm) to simplify that:

```
select id, cast(collect(reftype(id, name, details)) as reftypetab) as result
from reftab
group by id;

        ID RESULT(ID, NAME, DETAILS)                                                                                               
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(1, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(1, 'asf', 'agg'), REFTYPE(1, 'ash', 'add'), REFTYPE(1, 'asg', 'ass'))      
         3 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(3, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(3, 'ad', 'aa'))                                                            
         4 REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(4, 'ad', 'aa'), REFTYPE(4, 'as', 'a'))
```

If you want information from `basictab` as well you can use [a multiset operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators006.htm):

```
select bt.id, bt.name,
  cast(multiset(select reftype(rt.id, rt.name, rt.details)
    from reftab rt where rt.id = bt.id) as reftypetab) as result
from basictab bt;

        ID NAME       RESULT(ID, NAME, DETAILS)                                                                                               
---------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 aaa        REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(1, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(1, 'asg', 'ass'), REFTYPE(1, 'ash', 'add'), REFTYPE(1, 'asf', 'agg'))      
         2 aab        REFTYPETAB()                                                                                                            
         3 aaa        REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(3, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(3, 'ad', 'aa'))                                                            
         4 aaa        REFTYPETAB(REFTYPE(4, 'asd', 'aaa'), REFTYPE(4, 'as', 'a'), REFTYPE(4, 'ad', 'aa'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that what I found just a minute ago. That looks much better.

Comment: By the way do you have any experience with such structures? Is reading data such way much slower than doing outer join?

Comment: I imagine collect/multiset is going to be faster than your own function, but haven't tested to see how much.

Comment: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2010/01/cast-collect-versus-cast-multiset.html here is link with some comparison. Multiset seem to be faster. But another one: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=514 claims not exacly the same

Comment: @Kacper - thanks, though I'm not sure if that was the comparison the OP meant. I'd read that post before but forgotten about the extra type it creates for collect. If the intention is to combine data from both tables then multiset is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I need data combined so multiset is what I'm looking for. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Further research gave me another way to do that:

```
SELECT id, CAST(COLLECT(reftype(r.id, r.name, r.details)) AS reftypetab) AS customer_ids
    FROM reftab r group by id;
```

This looks much better but still I would ask if there are any opther ways to do that.

**EDIT**

Maybe that's not exactly what I was asking about but cursor expresion can give similar result.

```
 SELECT id, cursor(select reftype(r.id, r.name, r.details) from reftab r where r.id = b.id)  AS customer_ids
    FROM basictab b;
```